# wp_api add 2 inquery (my CPT) with single POST request

Tags: wordpress, facebook-chatbot, wp-api

i have messenger chatbot and if the user click **Get Started** i make **singel api call** *POST method* with $sender_id as title to add new post to my CPT inquery and when i look to wordpress panel i see 2 of them with same title and when make another api call with $sender_id as title it gives me the old one i can't figure why it happend from beginning Thanks in advenced

this my code to get ID of inquiry

```php
function get_inquiry_id($data){
 $return = []; $title=$data['title'];
 $return = get_page_by_title($title, OBJECT, 'inquiry');
 $return = $return->ID; return new WP_REST_Response($return, 200); 
} 
add_action('rest_api_init',function(){ 
     register_rest_route('chatbot/v1','/inquiry/(?P<title>\d+)',array( 
        'methods'=>'GET',
        'callback'=>'get_inquiry_id' 
   ));
 });
```

this my code for handel **Get Started** button

```php
if ( $payload == 'firsthand' ) {
    $sender_id = ''.$sender_id.'';
    $data_array = array( 
      "title"=>$sender_id 
   );
    callAPI('POST','http://alenke.test/wp-json/wp/v2/inquiry',json_encode($data_array));
  //rest of chatbot stuff
}
```

expected is to add `one single inquriy` with **POST** api call 
but it add `double inquiry` with same title

Comment: Your question title should be more descriptive. Do you believe, you can edit this further to make it more comprehensive?

Comment: i think it is get to the point with out writing the Q in title